# Focus CMAX 2.0 Petrol 2006 replacement autogearbox - does it require to recode the vehicle?

Tags: automatic-transmission

I've to replace automatic gearbox on Focus CMAX 2.0 Petrol 2006. I just wanted to know does it also require re-programming the vehicle or any part of it.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the transmission is not "serialized" to the Transmission Control Module (TCM).

HOWEVER, I'm guessing you have a Durashift or a [less likely]  Ford Powershift.  In the first case, Ford has a HUGE problem with these transmissions, much of which they tried to rememdy with software changes (TCM reflash).  In the sceond (Powershift) case, not as much - but this is a semi-automatic transmission.  Some clarification on exactly what transmission in in your 2006 CMAX and I can possibly provide a more accurate specific answer.

SO...     The answer to your simple question I beleive is "no".   But the answer to a bigger picture question is perhaps "yes, although not required, you may want the new TCM software that may mitigate the problem that caused your transmission failure in the first place (?!)"